# How to use MS ACCESS Replace function in asp.net c# program?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual Studio 2013  to develop a website application . I used the ASP.Net Web Application in Visual C#.

I am using the following code in the access desktop version and it does update my item but when i use this in the code it gives exception saying unidentified replace function.

```
  UPDATE tblGroups SET tblGroups.GroupID = replace(tblGroups.GroupID,"LANGLEY","Stessy")
```

WHERE tblGroups.GroupID Like "*LANGLEY*";

how can i use it in the program?

Help appreciated.